# Moving to other page when I click on map-d3

Tags: c#, json, d3.js

I have made a map in d3 for USA.
    I am getting the shape for usa with every state. When I move mouse on any state, it tells me the name of that shape.
    Now I want that if I click on any state, I should be moved to other page.
    How should I do this ?
    Is this possible, Actualy I want to display the map of each state when I click on that state.
    How should I move to other page?

The code of the map for displaying of usa is

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var w = 1560;
      var h = 900;
      var proj = d3.geo.mercator();
      var path = d3.geo.path().projection(proj);
      var t = proj.translate(); // the projection's default translation
      var s = proj.scale() // the projection's default scale

      var map = d3.select("#vis").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

      var axes = map.append("svg:g").attr("id", "axes");

      var xAxis = axes.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", t[0])
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", t[0])
        .attr("y2", h);

      var yAxis = axes.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", t[1])
        .attr("x2", w)
        .attr("y2", t[1]);

      var uk = map.append("svg:g").attr("id", "uk");
 d3.json("tryusa.json", function (json) {
          uk.selectAll("path")
          .data(json.features)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
         .attr("d", path)
        .append("svg:title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.properties.name; })

      });
      svg.selectAll(".subunit")
    .data(topojson.object(uk, uk.objects.subunits).geometries)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function (d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
    .attr("d", path);

      function redraw() {
          var tx = t[0] * d3.event.scale + d3.event.translate[0];
          var ty = t[1] * d3.event.scale + d3.event.translate[1];
          proj.translate([tx, ty]);

          // now we determine the projection's new scale, but there's a problem:
          // the map doesn't 'zoom onto the mouse point'
          proj.scale(s * d3.event.scale);

          // redraw the map
          uk.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);

          // redraw the x axis
          xAxis.attr("x1", tx).attr("x2", tx);

          // redraw the y axis
          yAxis.attr("y1", ty).attr("y2", ty);
      }
  </script>
```

I have a json file named tryusa.json. I am getting displayed the map by this json file.
I want to move to other page ?  How should I proceed ? Is it possible ? 
Is there some other way ? The platform I am using is C#.
Please help me out. I am really new to d3.

Comment: Have you tried to add .on("click", function (){window.open("target_url")} to your svg object (should be at the end just after .text(...) )

Comment: No I am not getting anything..
d3.json("tryusa.json", function (json) {
          uk.selectAll("path")
          .data(json.features)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
         .attr("d", path)
         .attr("Response.Redirect", "Default.aspx")
        .append("svg:title")
       // 
        .text(function (d) { return d.properties.name; })
        .on("click", function () { window.open("Default3.aspx") })
      });


I tried this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the code you provided in the comments you have:

```
d3.json("tryusa.json", function (json) { 
    uk.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features) 
    .enter().
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("Response.Redirect", "Default.aspx")
    .append("svg:title")
    .text(function (d) { return d.properties.name; })
    .on("click", function () { window.open("Default3.aspx") }) 
});
```

So, here you add the `on` listener to the `svg:title` element. Thus you would have to click on the tooltip or something like that. 
So, I think you should just put the `on` listener on the path:

```
d3.json("tryusa.json", function (json) { 
    uk.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features) 
    .enter().
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("Response.Redirect", "Default.aspx")
    .on("click", function () { window.open("Default3.aspx") })
    .append("svg:title")
    .text(function (d) { return d.properties.name; }) 
});
```

To be more precise, everything behind `append` will be encapsulated inside this tag.

Comment: Yes thats working. thanks alot.
If i think of displaying different map of each state . Then what should i do ? If I click on california then map of california should come, if i click on illinois, the the map of illinois should come. How to map different pages by clicking on different sections.

Comment: Also If i want to display different color on mouse over event, then would this statement not work ?
I wrote 
.on("mouseover", function () { d3.select(this).style("fill", "aqua"); })

Comment: See my answer to the specific question you asked for colors: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15517477/1041692
I would also add that for the redirections it is the same you can use the function, as you already do for the text to compute any property.