# Displaying different colors on the map or displaying color on mouse over event

Tags: json, d3.js

```
I have made a map in d3 for usa. Now I want to apply different color as soon as i move my mouse on the province area or from first have many colors to the map.

My code is :
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var w = 1560;
      var h = 900;
      var color = d3.scale.category10();
      var proj = d3.geo.mercator();
      var path = d3.geo.path().projection(proj);
      var t = proj.translate(); // the projection's default translation
      var s = proj.scale() // the projection's default scale

      var map = d3.select("#vis").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

      var axes = map.append("svg:g").attr("id", "axes");

      var xAxis = axes.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", t[0])
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", t[0])
        .attr("y2", h);

      var yAxis = axes.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", t[1])
        .attr("x2", w)
        .attr("y2", t[1]);


      var uk = map.append("svg:g").attr("id", "uk");
 d3.json("tryusa.json", function (json) {
          uk.selectAll("path")
          .data(json.features).on("mouseover", function () { d3.select(this).style("fill", "aqua"); })
        .enter().append("svg:path")
         .attr("d", path)
          .on("click", click)
          .on("click", function () { window.open("Default3.aspx") })
        .append("svg:title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.properties.name; })

      });

      svg.selectAll(".subunit")
    .data(topojson.object(uk, uk.objects.subunits).geometries)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function (d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
    ;


      function redraw() {
          var tx = t[0] * d3.event.scale + d3.event.translate[0];
          var ty = t[1] * d3.event.scale + d3.event.translate[1];
          proj.translate([tx, ty]);

          // now we determine the projection's new scale, but there's a problem:
          // the map doesn't 'zoom onto the mouse point'
          proj.scale(s * d3.event.scale);

          // redraw the map
          uk.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);

          // redraw the x axis
          xAxis.attr("x1", tx).attr("x2", tx);

          // redraw the y axis
          yAxis.attr("y1", ty).attr("y2", ty);
      }



  </script>
```

I tried few things like mouse over event, but I am unable to get the result.

I also tried using the inbuilt function for automatically displaying different colors.
But also I am unable to get that. 
I am new to d3
Would you please help me.
Color can be placed on mouse over event or from first. Anything would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an argument on the function you use to fill (and for everything else):

```
.data(json.features)
.on("mouseover", function (d, i) { d3.select(this).style("fill", d.color); })
```

With color being one of the properties of each field of the `json.features` array. In this function, the argument `d` represents the data (here the state), and `i` represents the index of the state in the `json.features` array.

An example implementation can be seen for the color of the nodes in this d3 example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Comment: Can you build a jsfiddle please?

Comment: wer should i keep the json file in the jsfiddle ?

Comment: You can't just put a sample of the json file in the script as a variable and comment the lines about the use of json as it is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: I build JSfiddle...i am not getting the colors..on the map.. :(